# Set width of title in Kendo data viz charts

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to set the width of the title element of my kendo charts so that they wrap to the line below when they reach a certain width.

Any idea which property I need to set? or how to use a template to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible with the current version of Kendo Charts.

In the past when I have needed titles anything more than simple text I have removed the title from the chart and placed it in a div above the chart.